# Why Magento 2 Google Shopping ads has very bad reviews?

Tags: magento2.2.3, review

I'm going to install Google Shopping Ads extension for my store.
https://marketplace.magento.com/magento-google-shopping-ads.html#

My store version is CE 2.4.3-p2, not 2.3 as previously stated.
My first question is
This extension is compatible with my store version?

My second question is..
Why this extension has many bad reviews?
This really has many bugs? Magento team is still struggling to solve the issues?
I'm currently checking the latest version 3.0.1. I want to know whether this latest version has also the known issue.
By the way, I've already installed it in my development site. Still, it looks fine. I am not seeing any blank screen(Many bad feedbacks say that they were seeing blank screen after they installed it)

My third question is..
Can I test it in my development site as well?
I am not doing the test now because our Google Merchant Center is only linked with our product site.
How can I test it for my development site? I really want to make sure 100% before I go to the production site with this extension.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about Magento 2.2.3 version. But this module is already added at the core module List at Magento 2.3 version. You can find that module at `vendor/magento/google-shopping-ads/` in Magento 2.3.4 version.

So, I think you can use this module at your module2.2.3 version.